# How am I able to run Tensor Core instructions without actually having Tensor Cores?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, hardware

I'm using CUDA's WMMA API to multiply fragments on the GTX 1660 Ti. This GPU doesn't have Tensor Cores, but when I look at the SASS generated for my code I see HMMA.1688.F32 instructions, which are Tensor Core instructions! How can that happen?

Relevant information:

- NVIDIA confirming my card doesn't have Tensor Cores: https://www.nvidia.com/en-eu/geforce/10-series/ (Technology Features table comparing GTX 10, GTX 16 and RTX 20 Series).
- HMMA.1688.F32 instructions linked to Tensor Core units:

  - https://developer.download.nvidia.com/video/gputechconf/gtc/2019/presentation/s9839-discovering-the-turing-t4-gpu-architecture-with-microbenchmarks.pdf
  - https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9139835 (account required to access, but more detailed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For code binary compatibility, the "non-tensor-core" members of the Turing family have [hardware in the SM](https://www.anandtech.com/show/13973/nvidia-gtx-1660-ti-review-feat-evga-xc-gaming/2) that will process tensor core instructions, albeit at a relatively low throughput, compared to a tensor core unit.